# Paginator data don't show well in livewire "public property [posts] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]"

Tags: php, laravel

I like to use livewire instead of controller

```
public function index()
{
  return view('advert.index', [
'posts' => Advert::latest()->filter(
            request(['search', 'category', 'author'])
        )->paginate(18)->withQueryString()
  ]);
}
```

in livewire `<livewire:advert.home :querys="request(['search', 'category', 'author'])">`

```
public function mount($querys)
{
    $this->querys = $querys;
}

public function render()
{
    $this->posts = Advert::latest()->filter([$this->querys])->paginate($this->perPage)->withQueryString();
}
```

but nothing work
it is mostly say

> Livewire component's [advert.home] public property [posts] must be of
> type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or
> private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript
> doesn't need to access them.

I am lost i use this but it don't work well and show error above. and look same data passed to livewire component.

and there is no difference between livewire $this->posts and 'posts' from controller i can't figure about that.

like
'posts' dd($posts) from controller

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#1412 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1402 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => App\Models\Advert {#1409 ▼
        #with: array:3 [▶]
        #fillable: array:8 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "adverts"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #withCount: []
        +preventsLazyLoading: false
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:12 [▶]
        #original: array:12 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #classCastCache: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:3 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
      1 => App\Models\Advert {#1410 ▼
        #with: array:3 [▶]
        #fillable: array:8 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "adverts"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #withCount: []
        +preventsLazyLoading: false
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:12 [▶]
        #original: array:12 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #classCastCache: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:3 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 18
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "https://awento.ddns.net/search"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}
```

and livewire $this->posts

ddd($posts)

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#1470 ▼
  #total: 2
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1458 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => App\Models\Advert {#1465 ▼
        #with: array:3 [▶]
        #fillable: array:8 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "adverts"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #withCount: []
        +preventsLazyLoading: false
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:12 [▶]
        #original: array:12 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #classCastCache: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:3 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
      1 => App\Models\Advert {#1467 ▼
        #with: array:3 [▶]
        #fillable: array:8 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: "adverts"
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #withCount: []
        +preventsLazyLoading: false
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:12 [▶]
        #original: array:12 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #classCastCache: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:3 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 15
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "https://awento.ddns.net"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}
```

Comment: make dd($this->posts) in render method and see what you're getting, seem isn't a proper value for livewire rendering

Comment: @Prospero thanks now i updated that good information.

Answer (score 0):

After some trail and error i realise the issue is with whole data if we arrange in some form of data that there will be no issue. So Now i create a array for transfer data with some foreach. If there is another better way please let me know.

```
    $postss = Advert::latest()->filter($this->querys)->paginate($this->perPage)->withQueryString();
    $posts = array();
    
    foreach($postss as $post)
    {
        array_push($posts, $post);
    }
    $this->posts = $posts;
```

It seem paginate don't work in livewire using limit now.